# Internet Explorer file download "open" allows editing of source file

Tags: html, internet-explorer, intranet

My site will be viewed exclusively in Internet explorer 9

I have a small intranet site. On this site i want to allow my users to download files.

When they click the link they get the standard 3 options "Open, save, Save as..", but whenever the user clicks open, it allows them to edit directly in my file, instead of downloading a local copy, they can then edit.

Am i missing something crucial here? 
Is there any way i can have IE9 always download a local copy, before allowing editing?

I initiate the download with the following:

```
    function onDownload() {
        document.location = "../DUMP" + kunde + ".csv";
    }
```

Comment: Do you serve the site using a web server or via `file://` protocol?

Comment: Through the file:// protocol, sorry for not including this.

Comment: Then use a web server. Of course the file protocol just opens the local file. A web server would send a copy through the wire, that's something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
document.location = "../DUMP" + kunde + ".csv";
```

with

```
document.location = "http://yourhost/path/DUMP" + kunde + ".csv";
```

(you have to use http:// instead of file:// protocol to force downloading instead of opeining)

Comment: This sounds like a likely winner.

Comment: Real winner here is Prinzhorn (see his first comment!).

Comment: Ill mark this as the correct answer, just because i cant mark Prinzhorn , but you both put me on the right direction. Thanks for helping me out, i got it working now.